# What is the purpose of row[/\w+/] in this code?

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary, block

What exactly is the line `row[/\w+/]` doing in the following situation?

```
fields = rows.shift.map{ |row| 
  row[/\w+/]
}
```

I understand that the first value is removed from *rows*, its values are all passed into the block and replaced by the value returned from the block. But what is `[/\w+/]` doing to the value? In this case each row is an array of alphanumeric strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see how the string index operator `[]` works [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

For example, if you pass a number (`row[5]`) it returns a substring containing the character at position 5 (0 being the first). But when a regular expression is used instead of a number, it returns the first substring that matches the regex.

In this particular case the regex is matching one or more word characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _

```
"abcd efg hij"[/w+/] #=> "abcd"
"abcd_efg hij"[/w+/] #=> "abcd_efg"
```

Answer (score 3):

Anything between two slashes is a [regular expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html). In this case `\w` matches any word character (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`) and the `+` indicates 1 or more characters. So this code will find the first occurrence of a word in the given string and discard the rest.

Comment: Thanks. I realised it was a regex. So it will reject anything after a space or an underscore?